# Justify entire document in the ireports (RMarkdown) template

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

When using the `ireports` template (RMarkdown), is there a way to justify (both sides) the entire document? Looking for a way to do this in my YAML or within the TeX file.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Can you not just print the report, and justify within the printer settings you want both sides printing? or else a digital PDF view will be the same either both sides or not